# Error executing specific lines of a python library on another computer as exe file

Tags: python, exe, python-3.7, cx-freeze, smtplib

my code is very simple python, it stores a "Hello World" in a variable, and then calls by my email GMAIL and sends the data stored within the variable, until and all right

then I turned it into .exe (with cx_Freeze), and both the .py and .exe files were running perfectly on my computer, and sending me the message via email!

however, after I tried to run the .exe file on another computer (I exported the entire executable folder and installed python on the other computer as a precaution), it simply stops running when it comes to sending the email, and closes the console by itself. ; -;

it stops executing when calling by smtplib:

`import smtplib`

How can I solve this problem, I want to run my files on other machines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two machines may have different OS or CPUS, this could be an issue. Have you tried to transfer the source (python) code, and compile it on the other machine? That should fix the issue, and if you want to run it on many different machines, consider compiling it on the machine you would like to run it on, and then upload that file. Cheers!

Comment: but what if I don't want, for example, to let the person on the other computer see the source code, after all, if I send the source code to a friend's PC and compile it, he can see inside the smtplib functions. where is my email and password in the file

Comment: @WardyGuardian You can compile it on a machine with the same OS and hardware, and then save *that* executable. You can then send that executable to the person. This is why many downloads for programs without installers have types for each OS.

Comment: @WardyGuardian additionally, if your email and password are in the file you may want to change that because it could be decompiled.

Comment: is there any way I can send something to my email through python without my password being visible to the code?